# Backend Layout in TS file in TYPO3 CMS 7.6.18 how to get it working?

Tags: templates, typo3, fluid

To be able to use different templates in a TYPO3 CMS 7.6.18 setup. I include a pageTSConfig.ts file with a backend layout looking like this. (see also this pastebin: https://pastebin.com/BcYKrYKh and this how it looks like in the TYPO3 object browser: https://pastebin.com/LVXqNUZC

```
### Backend Layouts #####

mod.web_layout.BackendLayouts{
1 {
  title = Standaard Layout
  config {
  backend_layout {
    colCount = 2
    rowCount = 1
    rows {
        1 {
            columns {
                1 {
                    name = linker_inhoud
                    colPos = 1
                }
                2 {
                    name = midden_inhoud
                    colPos = 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

  }
}


}
```

Since the BE-Layout is done with a file, in my TSconfig.ts I have added pagets__0 to it like the manual mentioned. Still this is not working. What Am I missing here? This is a part of the TSconfig I have in place here is the complete config:

```
page.10.file.stdWrap.cObject = CASE
page.10.file.stdWrap.cObject {
    key.data = levelfield:-1, backend_layout_next_level, pagelayout, slide
    key.override.field = pagelayout
    default = TEXT
    default.value = fileadmin/templates/index.html
    pagets__0 = TEXT
    pagets__0.value = fileadmin/templates/index.html
    pagets__1 = TEXT
    pagets__1.value = fileadmin/templates/layouts/small_header_page.html
    pagets__2 = TEXT
    pagets__2.value = fileadmin/templates/layouts/alternatieve_pagina.html
}
```

All to be included with:

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between "backend_layout", which is a the name of a real database field that can be fetched by "levelfield" and "pagelayout", which is a kind of virtual field to get rid of the "levelfield" approach.

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/DataTypes/Gettext/Index.html#pagelayout

```
key.data = pagelayout
```

should do the whole job for you and **only in this case** you can use stuff like

```
pagets__x
```

to access the actual layout.

So your code should either be:

```
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10.file.cObject = CASE
page.10.file.cObject {
    key.data = pagelayout
    default = TEXT
    default.value = fileadmin/templates/index.html
    pagets__0 = TEXT
    pagets__0.value = fileadmin/templates/index.html
    pagets__1 = TEXT
    pagets__1.value = fileadmin/templates/layouts/small_header_page.html
    pagets__2 = TEXT
    pagets__2.value = fileadmin/templates/layouts/alternatieve_pagina.html
}
```

or it should be

```
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10.file.cObject = CASE
page.10.file.cObject {
    key.data = levelfield:-1, backend_layout_next_level, slide
    key.override.field = backend_layout
    default = TEXT
    default.value = fileadmin/templates/index.html
    1 = TEXT
    1.value = fileadmin/templates/layouts/small_header_page.html
    2 = TEXT
    2.value = fileadmin/templates/layouts/alternatieve_pagina.html
}
```

But not a mix of both approaches.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Tried to use your first sample but still get not the right result. So I have the pageTsconfig and the TSconfig if I use the first sample where to put the variables than? 
variables {
      siteName = TEXT
      siteName.value = thissite.com
      pageTitle = TEXT
      pageTitle.data = page:title
      content < styles.content.get
 content_main < styles.content.get
 content_main.select.where = colPos = 0
content_column_1 < styles.content.get content_column_1.select.where = colPos = 1

Comment: This is what I have in the object browser. https://pastebin.com/6weZAHbM 
Seems to be quite easy but it drives me crazy :) Can anyone show me the complete set-up? So the TSconfig part and the pageTSconfig part when using the file based back-end layout. a paste-bin or so would be great!

Comment: The given solution is a snippet for the TypoScript setup of your TypoScript-Template - not TSconfig.

Page TSconfig is what you do to configure that layout as shown in the first code block of your question.

The TypoScript setup snippet will get you a different file for each defined backend layout value of a page or a fall back file for any other value.

I slightly modified it, since it got one superfluous stdWrap level and had been missing the FLUIDTEMPLATE part. Now it should be clear, where to put the variables of that FLUIDTEMPLATE.

Comment: Might sound stupid, but also with al your good advises it still does not work. I do not get any template offered to select in the BE (also nothing in the FE). Seems that I'm not the only one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42901596/typo3-7-6-2-how-to-store-backend-layout-into-page-txt-file
Could someone publish a working sample on paste-bin or github? An other question, do I need to activate a module in Typo3 to get this working or is it a core feature? Thanks W.

Comment: Of course you won't get a frontend output, when you already can't select the layout in the backend. At least this means, that the TypoScript setup is currently not the problem.

So how and where do you include the PageTSconfig block that you posted as the first one of your example?

Comment: In the root-page of the tree, at the tab resource I include a file pageTSConfig_general.ts in that page I include the page_TS file for the backend template selection like this:  <INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:fileadmin/templates/ts/page_backend_layouts/pageTSConfig.ts">

Answer (score 0):

Before I tell you what might be wrong with your code, let me explain you a few things.

You have placed your templates in the fileadmin directory. This is not the place where to put these files any longer, because the fileadmin is a public place for resources like images, videos or documents. It might be available for every backend user in the filelist and the editor should not be able to edit the template in any case. The suggested way to handle your templates is to put them into an own extension  that can be installed via the extension manager.

In your pastebin snippets, there is a line with `userFunc = tx_templavoila_pi1->main_page`, you may mixing up stuff in your installation and don't want to use FLUIDTEMPLATE alongside templavoila, because it could be confusing what rendering method is used for what stuff on your page. Better stick to templavoila or Fluid for the entirety of the TYPO3 installation.

Now, you have these lines in your TypoScript:

```
key.data = levelfield:-1, backend_layout_next_level, pagelayout, slide
key.override.field = pagelayout
```

There is no field `pagelayout` in the pages records. The field you rather want to address is `backend_layout`.

Comment: I don't agree with "You have placed your templates in the fileadmin directory. This is not the place where to put these files any longer, because the fileadmin is a public place for resources like images, videos or documents." You can restrict access with "Filemount" or a separate folder as "File Storage". No separate extension needed for a simple backend layout. Where you get this info from about this suggested way @Kevin Ditscheid ?

Comment: To make it quick, have a look at these slides: https://de.slideshare.net/benjaminkott/typo3-the-anatomy-of-sitepackages and follow this blogpost by Helmut Hummel about static resources: http://insight.helhum.io/post/121359113745/resources-the-image-view-helper-and-fal-in-typo3 The fileadmin-approach is a very ancient way of handling your site templates and should not be encouraged anymore. You could also ask on the TYPO3 slack channel and almost everyone would give you the same answer.

Comment: @KevinDitscheid upvoted. Static files never belonged in fileadmin in the first place but certainly no longer.

Comment: Now having all the files residing in a nice extension (no more fileadmin) I gave the "multi templating" a new try. In this pastebin all the relevant files and / what I can see in the Template / Pageinfo. https://pastebin.com/EMfpz7vp   I have tree templates but I only get the same DefaultTemplate in the FE. I used the set-up as displayed here with the Pagets__  I can select a back-end and see that applied but not the FE template So what is wrong with my settup?? Thanks
W.